# Transform issue when hovering element with tailwind

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I'm struggling to make an animation on a SVG using Tailwind.
I'd like to make a `-translate-y-1` hover transformation when hovering one my SVG layer.

I can make it react to opacity, but when trying to use transform it basically stop working.
Here's my svg code

```
  <g>
    <path d="M59.7203 28.0629L40.2131 18.2707C35.7585 16.029 28.5381 16.029 24.0835 18.2707L4.5763 28.0629C0.121702 30.3046 0.121702 33.9259 4.5763 36.1676L24.0835 45.9597C28.5381 48.1892 35.7585 48.1892 40.2131 45.9597L59.7203 36.1676C64.1749 33.9259 64.1749 30.3046 59.7203 28.0629Z" fill="#C1C1C1"/>
    <path d="M32.1485 48.3C29.1258 48.3 26.0908 47.7211 23.7778 46.5633L4.28282 36.7711C1.88419 35.5641 0.5625 33.9136 0.5625 32.1152C0.5625 30.3169 1.88419 28.6664 4.28282 27.4594L23.7778 17.6672C28.4037 15.3516 35.9056 15.3516 40.5193 17.6672L60.0265 27.4594C62.4129 28.6541 63.7346 30.3169 63.7346 32.1152C63.7346 33.9136 62.4129 35.5641 60.0265 36.7711L40.507 46.5633C37.8794 47.7591 35.0194 48.3483 32.1363 48.2877L32.1485 48.3ZM32.1485 17.2607C29.3338 17.2607 26.5191 17.8027 24.3897 18.8743L4.87024 28.6664C2.98561 29.6149 1.89643 30.8712 1.89643 32.1152C1.89643 33.3593 2.98561 34.6033 4.87024 35.5641L24.3775 45.3439C28.6607 47.4994 35.6363 47.4994 39.9196 45.3439L59.4268 35.5517C61.3115 34.6033 62.3884 33.3593 62.3884 32.1029C62.3884 30.8466 61.3115 29.6149 59.4146 28.6664L39.9196 18.8743C37.4799 17.7653 34.825 17.2182 32.1485 17.2731V17.2607Z" fill="black"/>
  </g>
  <g class="transform hover:opacity-75">
    <path style="filter: drop-shadow(2px 4px 6px black);" d="M59.7203 13.0113L40.2131 3.21917C35.7585 0.977441 28.5381 0.977441 24.0835 3.21917L4.5763 13.0113C0.121702 15.2407 0.121702 18.862 4.5763 21.116L24.0835 30.8958C28.5381 33.1376 35.7585 33.1376 40.2131 30.8958L59.7203 21.116C64.1749 18.8743 64.1749 15.2407 59.7203 13.0113Z" fill="#E6007E"/>
    <path d="M32.149 33.8273C29.0528 33.8273 25.9566 33.2115 23.5335 32.0044L4.03851 22.2122C0.538468 20.4509 0 18.2338 0 17.0637C0 15.8935 0.52623 13.6641 4.02627 11.9028L23.5335 2.11063C28.3675 -0.303538 35.9305 -0.303538 40.7645 2.11063L60.2717 11.9028C63.7717 13.6641 64.2857 15.8935 64.2857 17.0637C64.2857 18.2338 63.7595 20.4509 60.2717 22.2122L40.7522 32.0044C38.0524 33.2542 35.108 33.8772 32.1367 33.8273H32.149ZM32.149 2.77575C29.2853 2.77575 26.6174 3.31771 24.6349 4.3154L5.12768 14.1075C3.42661 14.9697 2.45982 16.0413 2.45982 17.0637C2.45982 18.086 3.43885 19.1576 5.12768 20.0198L24.6227 29.7996C26.6174 30.7973 29.2853 31.3516 32.149 31.3516C35.0126 31.3516 37.6805 30.7973 39.6753 29.7996L59.1703 20.0075C60.8713 19.1576 61.8381 18.086 61.8381 17.0514C61.8381 16.0167 60.8591 14.9574 59.1703 14.1075L39.6753 4.32772C37.3107 3.25993 34.7401 2.73405 32.149 2.78807V2.77575Z" fill="black"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Which is wrapped in a rails helper

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
  <%= inline_svg_tag('autocollant-personnalise-logo.svg', class:'my-2 mx-auto')  %>
<% end %>
```

I have no clue at all why it's not working. If anyone have a clue on that